# How do I configure my web scraper to avoid a redirect loop?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to grab the HTML from Metacritic, e.g.,

https://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/all/pc/filtered

using the Python `requests` library. However, Metacritic appears to be detecting that I'm not using a real web browser and is sending me into a redirect loop. I gather this is probably related to browser cookies, but I have no idea which one(s) Metacritic cares about. Is this approach feasible, or do I need to use something like Selenium?

Comment: Metacritic may be using anti-scraping techniques such as bot detection to prevent automated requests from non-browser clients like Python requests. This can result in a redirect loop or an error message.
Using a headless browser like Selenium can be a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is to set the headers in the request.

```
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    h = requests.get(url=URL_PREFIX+platform["value"]+URL_SUFFIX, headers=headers).content
```

Answer (score 0):

`requests` has a built in way to avoid redirects.

Since you didnt include any code in your question, im assuming you're using `requests.get()`

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com', allow_redirects=False)
print(response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your browser's devtools to see what headers it is sending and send the same ones with requests.

You can also use the [scrapy](https://scrapy.org) framework for building web crawlers.